# Unable to download Falco in Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux

I am trying to install Falco in Kali Linux. The official download documentation can be found [here](https://falco.org/docs/getting-started/installation/).

When I try and execute the command

```
apt-get update -y
```

I am getting following error.

```
E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/debian kali-rolling Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Also when I run the command :

```
apt-get install -y falco
```

I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package falco
```

I tried updating the entire OS and even installed Linux headers still the same.
I tried doing it as a root user and as a new user too. The errors are the same. How to install Falco in Kali Linux?

Comment: Did you read the error messages?

Comment: Yes. The above highlighted ones are error messages only @StarCat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have tow error:

1). The first one come from docker-ce repository, because docker-ce doesn't support `kali-rolling` codename, to correct the problem use the following command:

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
```

Then install it properly: [Installing Docker on Kali Linux](https://www.kali.org/docs/containers/installing-docker-on-kali/)

```
printf "%s\n" "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian buster stable" \
| sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker-ce.list

curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg \
| sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
```

2). The second error message come from flaco repository.

To install `flaco` use the [Linux generic (binary package)](https://falco.org/docs/getting-started/installation/#linux-binary) method :

```
curl -L -O https://dl.bintray.com/falcosecurity/bin/x86_64/falco-0.27.0-x86_64.tar.gz
tar -xvf falco-0.27.0-x86_64.tar.gz
cp -R falco-0.27.0-x86_64/* /
echo "alias flaco='falco-0.27.0-x86_64/usr/bin/falco'" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```